# Convert shape (it was chart in the beginning) to chart in illustrator

Tags: svg, charts, adobe, adobe-illustrator

My charts turned into regular shape after I saved it to SVG and re-opened the file. I am not sure if it was that caused the problem but that is all what I know and now, since it turned into regular shape, I can't edit the data anymore.

here is the image :
[image]

And for your info, it is not donut chart, it is just collection of pie chart.

so my question is, how to convert it back so I can edit the data chart.

Comment: Charts turned into regular shape after you saved it to SVG since svg format does not support AI chart tools capabilities.

Comment: so there is no way I can convert them back? maybe by saving to Ai or something?

Comment: I don't catch, you lost original ai file with chart?

Comment: for some reason the app wont me save it using Ai format file, that was why i saved it using svg format. well it seems i need to re-create the charts manually. thanks anyway.